# Novato em aplicativos. Por onde começar?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, apache-cordova, app

Olá.
Desenvolvo com Ruby on Rails e PHP a algum tempo. Gostaria de criar um aplicativo agora...
Queria partir do ponto que ja sei, ou seja, usar uma dessas duas linguagens para criar o aplicativo.
Vi que existem ferramentas que fazem aplicativo em HTML 5, como o PhoneGap e o Sencha touch. E eu gostaria de partir desse ponto.
O grande porém é que eu gostaria de utilizar mapas, geolocalização e alguma API de lugares, bares, restaurantes, etc.

Dei uma olhada no Mapbox mas nao tenho certeza se ele faz esse tipo de coisa, também não sei se o PhoneGap vai me oferecer o que preciso quanto a isso.
Preciso de algumas dicas de por onde começar, algumas APIs recomendadas.
Obrigado.

Comment: recomendo dar uma olhada no Ionic http://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se vai desenvolver com o PhoneGap, pode usar qualquer API de mapas que funcione na web, como [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/), [Bing Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx) e [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page). Para obter a posição atual do dispositivo que está usando sua aplicação, você usa o [plugin de geolocalização do PhoneGap](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md).

Answer (score 0):

Se for começar eu indicaria o https://flutter.dev/

Além de ser uma novidade, está se firmando muito bem no mercado e além disto tem muitos plugins

Você pode pesquisa no seguinte endereço: https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=maps

Eu já pesquisei maps para você ver um exemplo

E além disto você poderá gerar seus apps para Android e iOS

Espero que ajude